ApexCharts display only first and last x-axis labels
I'm using an ApexCharts bar chart.
I want to display only the first and last x-axis labels, as the text is overlapping when I display all the values.
For example, in the screenshot below I want to display 0 and 350000.


You can either style based on the number of ticks (if the data range will vary), or you can provide the exact tick interval to be used to match the range of your data.
Number of ticks: Using the tickAmount option you can specify for there to only be one tick (in addition to 0). This will then add a tick at the max value of the range.
options = {
  xaxis: {
    tickAmount: 1
  }
}

Tick interval: If the range of your data is static, then you could alternatively use the stepSize option, setting the stepSize to your max value, e.g. 350000.
options = {
  xaxis: {
    stepSize: 350000 // max value in the data
  }
}

